# Windows Phone 8 trial expiration time

Tags: windows-phone-8

On WP8 there is a LicenseInformation class to get to know whether the app is in trial state or is already bought.

Now what I want to do is to make my app to work in trial mode only for 7 days (and expire afterwards).

The docs on MSDN are now somewhat misleading on this topic, so I have these questions after reading them.

1. Is LicenseInformation.ExpirationDate useless for my purpose? ["This API always returns 9999 – 12 – 31 (ETERNITY_FILETIME_TIME)."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.expirationdate.aspx) It seems that trial licence itself never expires, is this correct?
2. Can LicenseInformation.IsActive be used instead? "[May return false if the license is missing, **expired**, or revoked.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.isactive.aspx)", "[IsTrial returns true even after the trial period ends. IsActive, however, will return false after the trial period ends.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.istrial.aspx)" If so, how can I set the expiration date?

Thank you!

Comment: perhaps because you are in debug mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, the expiry time is always the DateTime.Max value.
2. No. This is not adequate for your needs.

There is nothing in the Trial APIs to enable expiry after a certain time limit. You must implement this functionality yourself.

To implement expiry after 7 days of use you must do the following:

- Record the date when the app is first used.
- When subsequently started check if still in trial mode and if more than 7 days since first use.
- If both of these tests return true then assume the trial has expired and take appropriate action in your app.

You can track the first use date/time in Isolated storage but be aware that if the user uninstalls and then reinstalls they will be able to run the trial again.

As an alternative you will need to store the device Id and the first use date/time on your own webserver. You then check against that data as the user can't reset it.
The downsides to this are the need to run the server and determining what should happen if the app can't connect to the server. (No network access or server down.)

Things get further complicated if you want to consider users with multiple devices but that's probably beyond what reasonably needs considering.

Comment: I'm coming across the same confusion with the trial system and contradicting explanations. I thought that the OS will automatically lock users out of an app if the trial has expired. There's still the problem that they can re-install the app to reset the trial, but I'm fine with that being the case. In the code we haven't handled trial state at all - we want to provide full functionality - and we want players to buy the game so that they don't lose their progress.

Comment: So my question is, does the OS do this automatically, or are we meant to write the code to handle it?

Comment: can the problem of user reinstalling app be resolved by storing device id and date in roaming data folder on mobile?

Comment: @Rorschach in Windows10 potentially. But users could always modify or delete that data